# jQuery calling VB.NET returning entire HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vb.net

I'm trying to call a server-side function from javascript using jQuery.

AJAX

```
function addAsset() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ServerMethods.aspx/AddAsset",
        data: '{}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

ServerMethods.aspx.vb

```
Public Class ServerMethods
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function AddAsset() As String

        Return "Hello"

    End Function

End Class
```

ServerMethods.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ServerMethods.aspx.vb" Inherits="AssetManager.ServerMethods" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

addAsset() is called when a button is clicked. When I try changing the dataType to text the entire HTML code comes back for ServerMethods. If the dataType is set to json it throws the error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'. I assume this is json trying to parse the HTML code. I'm not trying to neccessarily get a json response, I just want some kind of response, in this case I'm just trying to return "hello".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) class to serialize the data being returned from your web service. Then in the success handler from your .ajax() call you would deserialize it using `JSON.parse()`.

Webservice:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function AddAsset() As String
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize("Hello")
    Return serializedResult 
End Function
```

Javascript:

```
success: function (response) {
    var myHtml= JSON.parse(response);
    alert(myHtml);
}
```

Most modern browsers support `JSON.parse()`. In browsers that don't, you can use [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: Same parse error. Might it have something to do with my ServerMethods.aspx page (added it in the original email)?

Comment: @dagonal Did you serialize the result first? What is the value of `response` in your success handler?

Comment: I was using an older version of .NET so I didn't have the reference to JavaScriptSerializer. Now that I've upgraded it to .NET 4.0 my web app is through crazy errors =/

Comment: @dagonal JavaScriptSerializer is available from .NET 3.5 on. If you have to stay with .NET 2.0 for some reason you can try [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)